# Direct link for downloading Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP2 without clicking any button?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Are you aware of a direct link to download SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP2 without clicking any button?

I would like to build a bootstrapper package for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A link where you can directly download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express Edition without clicking any button is as follows:
For 32 Bit:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe

For 64 Bit:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe

Comment: Thanks! If I want to download the 64 bit version, should I change the link? It seems the 32-bit and the 64-bit to have the same download link. I want to build a bootstrapper package for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.